# HWND Change cursor when mouse Hover

Tags: c++, winapi, cursor, user32, hwnd

I need to change the cursor icon when the mouse hovers a certain HWND. I achieved the mouse cursor change with

```
SetClassLong(hWindow, GCL_HCURSOR, (LONG)LoadCursor (NULL, IDC_CROSS));
```

But it applies the cursor to each element which share the same class with the specified HWND. For example, in my case, the HWND is a Button element, and it's class is "Button", so all the buttons in my window will have the same cursor. How can I just change the cursor to a specified HWND? Something like this:

```
SetHwndCursor(hWindow, GCL_CURSOR, Cursor); //Invented function, just to make the example
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To show a different cursor than the class's default cursor, you need to handle the [`WM_SETCURSOR`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648382%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) message for the window and call `SetCursor` in response to `WM_SETCURSOR`. For a brief example, see [Displaying a Cursor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648380%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#_win32_Displaying_a_Cursor).

You'll need to subclass the button to override the button's WndProc to handle `WM_SETCURSOR`. Use [`SetWindowSubclass`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762102.aspx) to subclass the window (and then remove the subclassing with [`RemoveWindowSubclass`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762094.aspx) when the button is destroyed, in response to `WM_NCDESTROY`—see Raymond Chen's [Safer subclassing](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2003/11/11/55653.aspx) for details). [`SetWindowLongPtr`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644898%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is no longer recommended for subclassing windows.

Thanks to @IInspectable and @JonathanPotter for the information on `SetWindowSubclass`.

Comment: [Subclassing Controls](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773183.aspx) describes the disadvantages of using the old subclassing approach (`SetWindowLongPtr`), and explains the proper way.

Comment: All modern systems have comctl32.dll version 6. No one should be writing programs to target Windows 98 any more. And `SetWindowSubclass` was added in 5.8 anyway.

Answer (score 2):

I accomplish this by handling `WM_SETCURSOR` for the window in question and use `SetCursor`.

Comment: SetCursor changes the global cursor, not applied natively to a certain element, am i wrong? Thanks.

Comment: As soon as the mouse moves, the window it's over can/will set it to what it wants... including windows that your application doesn't own.  In effect, it applies only to a certain element.